# Why do we call null String?

Tags: java

I like to know why do we call null string. Where Strings are objects in java and objects can not be null only references can be null.

Can anybody elaborate on it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a bit of confusion here. I would expect 'null String' to be a String reference that doesn't actually reference a String (i.e. it's null). But [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28computer_programming%29) claims a 'null string' to be an empty string.

For this reason, I try to talk about null references - i.e. references that point to nothing at all, rather than a valid object. And (to be clear) empty Strings. A 'null String' to me means the same as a null reference, but the latter term is clearer to me.

Comment: +1 for the differentiation between "null" and "empty" in relationship to Strings.  A common misconception, in my experience.

Comment: Apache Commons Lang `StringUtils` makes clear distinction between "null", "empty" and "blank"... all useful distinctions.

Comment: @skaffman - what on earth is the difference between empty and blank??

Comment: @Roger, Containing whitespace versus a length of zero maybe?

Comment: @Dominic - whitespace versus empty, I would expect

Comment: @Dominic: An empty string is one with a length of zero. A blank string is one whose characters are either spaces or control characters. So an empty string is always blank, but a blank string isn't always empty.

Comment: @John and @Roger and @Brian - interesting, I've never come across that distinction before. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The expression "null string" simply means a reference of type "string" that references nothing (i.e. is "null").  It is a phrase that is commonly used but is not entirely correct as you point out.

It is is just a simpler way of expressing a concept in casual conversation, nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

The [JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/lexical.doc.html) defines empty strings and the null literal as well as the a null reference.

If an author introduces *null strings* he is supposed to define what exactly is meant by a null string.

Answer (score 0):

You can see it that way:

- **Objects** are instances of classes.
- **Object references** refer to none or a single object.

Here is an example:

```
String a; // object reference a has the value null
a = new String("Hello World"); // new object is assigned to reference a. Yes, I
                               // know that the string constructor should be avoided, but
                               // to show the point it is necessary
String b = a; // object references point to the same object
```

Objects references can be `null` and are `null` if there is no object assigned to it.
If you call such an object, a [NullPointerException](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) is thrown.

I assume that you are coming from C++. An Java object reference it much more like a C++ pointer as it has a null value, but in a safe way.

Answer (score 0):

For me, a *null string* is a `String` that is `null`:

```
String NULL = null;
```

And this is very different from an *empty string*:

```
String EMPTY = "";
```

Even if many sources ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28computer_programming%29), [Encyclopedia.com](http://www.encyclopedia.com/doc/1O11-nullstring.html), [Answers.com](http://www.answers.com/topic/null-string) to cite them) seem to consider that a *null string* and an *empty string* are the same thing.